# How do I generate random string array urls without repeating?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, random

I am trying to generate random string array urls in picasso, everything is working fine but it repeats, like i had 28 string array items when i start app some items are repeating but i want only 1 item at one time when random start

**This is my code**

```
     ImageView imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        random = new Random(); 
        int p=  random.nextInt(icons.length);
        Picasso.get().load(icons[p]).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of previously generated integers in an array/list and check the array each time you generate a new random number. This way, if the new integer generated already exists in the array, you generate a new one, until you have generated 28 numbers, after which you will have to clear the array and start over.

```
ImageView imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
Random random = new Random();
List<Integer> prevInts = new ArrayList<>();
Picasso.get().load(icons[randomUniqueInteger()]).into(imageView);

public int randomUniqueInteger(){
    int p = 0;
    do {
        p = random.nextInt(icons.length);
    } while(prevInts.contains(p));

    if ((prevInts.size + 1) == icons.length){
       prevInts.clear();
    }

    prevInts.add(p);

    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
ImageView imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
Random random = new Random();
List<Integer> cache = new ArrayList<>();
int p = 0;
do {
     p = random.nextInt(icons.length);
} while(cache.contains(p));
cache.add(p);

Picasso.get().load(icons[p]).into(imageView);
```

Comment: @RohanSaini it never repeats, it should be stuck in a loop till a unique not persisted number is generated, where are using this code? is it in a view holder?

Comment: @Yousef Shamass i am using it in pager adapter in Object instantiateItem